# Sort list by multiple fields and multiple criteria

Tags: java, android, list, sorting

I have the following code:

```
list.sort(Comparator
    .comparing(ProgrammData::getEnd)
    .thenComparing(ProgrammData::getStart).reversed());
```

My problem is that I want to have my list sorted by multiple things:
1.) Group them into future events and past events (By checking if the System.currentMilliseconds() is larger than the end timestamp)
2.) Sort future events by start ascending
3.) Sort past events by end descending

Can I do this with Java 8 Lambda or do I need another way of sorting the items?

Example:

```
events could look like this:
name, start, end
event1, 2022-02-220100, 2022-02-220300 
event2, 2022-02-220200, 2022-02-241800
event3, 2022-02-251200, 2022-02-281500
event4, 2022-02-261600, 2022-02-262100

if now() is 2022-02-221200 So the order should be:

event3 (next item in the future)
event4 (2nd next item in the future)
event2 (Ended closer to now than event1)
event1 (Longest in the past)
```

Comment: I think it is easier and more performant to separate future and past events, apply sort in each list accordingly, and then join them in a single list. You can also create you custom comparator, but then need to check if it is future or past event to return the correct sort order.

Comment: I can't change the data structure so seperating the events is not possible unfortunatelly. They need to be sorted after I received them.

Comment: @user754730 Shouldn't the correct ordering in your example be - event2 -> event3 -> event4 -> event1? If now() is 2022-02-221200 then event2 ending at 2022-02-241800 is in future and should be ordered by start with events 3 and 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understood this problem you rely on an *existing API* that expects a list of events and want them to be processed altogether as a **single list** ordered accordingly with their *start* and *end* date-time. And that is achievable.

I assume that the time-related event data stored inside a `ProgrammData` object is of type `String`. If it's not the case, and these fields are for instance of legacy type `Date` then only a couple of small changes need to be done.

My idea is to *encapsulate all functionality* inside the **utility class** `TwoWaySorting` so that all *implementation details are abstracted away*. And in the client code only this line `TwoWaySorting.getSorted(programmData)` is needed to produce a *sorted list* of events.

Since the responsibility of the `TwoWaySorting` class isn't related to the state all its behavior is marked with *static* modifier and its constructor is *private*. It has a **nested static class** `Element` which is a wrapper on top of the `ProgrammData` (if my assumption that `ProgrammData` is part of the existing IPA is correct then it must be used as is without any changes). So `Element`'s class concern is to represent the time-related data of the wrapped `ProgrammData` object in a convenient form for **sorting**.

That is a brief overview of what the method `getSorted()` does:

- it obtains an instance the **Comparator**, that is based on the *current time*;
- creates the *stream* over the list of events and *wraps* each event with an instance of the `Element` class;
- *sorts* the elements;
- extracts *original events* and collects them into a *list*.

To wrap an event the static method [`LocalDateTime.parse()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#parse(java.lang.CharSequence,java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter)) which accept a `CharSequence` and an appropriate [formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) is used to parse string-based time-related data.

The centerpiece of `TwoWaySorting` class is a **comparator** returned by the `getComparator()` method, let's examine it closely.

The first part of it is responsible for dividing the elements into two groups based on `currentTime`:

```
Comparator.<Element, Boolean>comparing(element -> element.getEnd().isBefore(currentTime))
```

As its name suggest the instance methed [`isBefore()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#isBefore(java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDateTime)) of the `LocalDateTime` class returns **true** if *this date-time* object **is before** the *date-time object* passed as an argument.

According to the natural sorting order of `boolean` values **false** comes before **true**. So for an invent that ends in the future `isBefore()` will yield **false**, which means that it'll appear at the *beginning* of the sorted list.

The second part of the **comparator** is responsible for ordering of the *past* and *future* events:

```
.thenComparingLong(element -> element.getEnd().isAfter(currentTime) ?
                                        element.getStart().toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.of("+00:00")) :
                                        element.getEnd().toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.of("+00:00")) * -1);
```

> **Returns**:
> a lexicographic-order comparator composed of **this** and then the **long sort key**

Method `thenComparingLong()` (*a quote from the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#thenComparingLong(java.util.function.ToLongFunction)) is shown above*) returns an **aggregated comparator** comprised of the *comparator* that was obtained previously (that separates *past* and *future* events) and a *comparator* thas is based on the `ToLongFunction` provided as an argument, which compares elements accordingly with `long` values extracted by that *function*.

Method `toEpochSecond()` extructs from a date-time object the number of *seconds* from the *epoch* as `long`.

*I assume that it is sufficient for this task because in the example time is described with a precision of **minutes**. `ZoneOffset` that is expected by `toEpochSecond()` as an argument, in this case, has no influence on the result, and offset for Greenwich can be substituted with any other valid offset.*

Since *future* events have to be sorted in **ascending order** value produced by the `toEpochSecond()` is used as is, for *past* events that must be sorted in **descending order** it's multiplied by `-1` to reverse the result of the comparison.

**Note:**

- in order to combine these **two comparators** described above together we have to provide generic type information explicitly, like that: `<Element,Boolean>comparing()`. Without an explicit declaration, the compiler has not enough data to determine the **type** of the variable `element`, and inside both `comparing()` and `thenComparingLong()` its type will be inferred as **`Object`**. If we used *only one* of these static methods the **type** of the `element` will be correctly inferred by the compiler as `Element` based on the *return type* of the method `getComparator()`. But for our case, we need to provide this information explicitly.

[*for information on the syntax of generic methods, take a look at this tutorial*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/methods.html)

`TwoWaySorting` **class**

```
public class TwoWaySorting {
    private static final DateTimeFormatter PD_FORMATTER
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-ddHHmm");

    private TwoWaySorting() {} // no way and no need to instantiate this class

    private static Comparator<Element> getComparator() {
        LocalDateTime currentTime = LocalDateTime.now();

        return Comparator.<Element, Boolean>comparing(element -> element.getEnd().isBefore(currentTime))
                         .thenComparingLong(element -> element.getEnd().isAfter(currentTime) ?
                                            element.getStart().toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.of("+00:00")) :
                                            element.getEnd().toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.of("+00:00")) * -1);
    }

    public static List<ProgrammData> getSorted(List<ProgrammData> programmData) {
        Comparator<Element> twoWayComparator = getComparator();

        return programmData.stream()
                .map(TwoWaySorting::parseData)
                .sorted(twoWayComparator)
                .map(Element::getData)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    private static Element parseData(ProgrammData data) {
        return new Element(data,
                           LocalDateTime.parse(data.getStart(), PD_FORMATTER),
                           LocalDateTime.parse(data.getEnd(), PD_FORMATTER));
    }

    private static class Element {
        private ProgrammData data;
        private LocalDateTime start;
        private LocalDateTime end;

        // constructor and getters
    }
}
```

This solution is meant to be *clean* and *reusable*. So in the `main()` apart from the *source list* there's only one line that obtains a sorted list and prints it on the console.

**Note:** `getSorted()` doesn't cause mutation of the source but creates a new list.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<ProgrammData> programmData = // a list dummy ProgrammData objects
            List.of(new ProgrammData("event1", "2022-02-220100", "2022-02-220300"),
                    new ProgrammData("event2", "2022-02-220200", "2022-02-241800"),
                    new ProgrammData("event3", "2022-02-251200", "2022-02-281500"),
                    new ProgrammData("event4", "2022-02-261600", "2022-02-262100"));

    TwoWaySorting.getSorted(programmData)
                 .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

**Output** (identical with the provided example)

```
ProgrammData [event3, 2022-02-251200, 2022-02-281500]
ProgrammData [event4, 2022-02-261600, 2022-02-262100]
ProgrammData [event2, 2022-02-220200, 2022-02-241800]
ProgrammData [event1, 2022-02-220100, 2022-02-220300]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
    final long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    list.sort((el1, el2) -> {
        if (el1.equals(el2)) {
            return 0;
        }
        boolean isEl1Future = el1.getEnd().getTime() > currentTime;
        boolean isEl2Future = el2.getEnd().getTime() > currentTime;
        if (isEl1Future != isEl2Future) {
            return isEl1Future ? -1 : 1;
        }
        if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(isEl1Future)) {
            return el1.getStart().before(el2.getStart()) ? -1 : 1;
        }
        return el1.getEnd().after(el2.getEnd()) ? -1 : 1;
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to kind of work! The grouping by future and past events works fine but the problem is that the ascending sorting of future and descending sorting of past events doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple things to notice. First, one is the `.thenComparing(...)` method, which is only taking place if the previous comparing results are equal. You can read more about its behavior in the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#thenComparing-java.util.Comparator-).

Second, if I were you I wouldn't bother to overuse the stream if I could solve it with one simple comparator. Assuming that you are looking for a new instance of the `ProgrammData` list, I wrote my code in stream style, but the Comparator can be used with the `List`'s `sort` method.

```
private List<ProgrammData> sortedProgramms(List<ProgrammData> dataList) {
    final LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
    return dataList.stream()
                    .sorted((e1, e2) -> {
                        if (e1.getStart().isAfter(now) && e2.getStart().isAfter(now)) {
                            return e1.getStart().compareTo(e2.getStart());
                        }
                        return e2.getEnd().compareTo(e1.getEnd());
                    })
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
 }
```

The LocalDateTime().now() is using System.currentTimeMillis() inside, if there is not a more accurate given clock.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! It doesn't seem to work as expected either. The grouping of future and past events seems to work but sorting future events ascending and past events descending doesn't work it seems.

Comment: Could you please provide an example, I don't get where is the mistake.  You asked in the original question about a sorter that sorts all the programs by their end descending, but if they are in the future, they must be sorted by their starting times ascending. It think it does the job, but I cant see which edge cases I missing.

Comment: I added an example to the question

Comment: The example does not match the description. You said that we group future/past events by end time. That way event2, event3, event4 will be the future events. Creating an ascending comparing by their start time will yield the order: event2, event3, event4 and then comes the only past event event1. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, sorry the example was only for part 2 and 3 of my question since you already group the items correctly with your snippet.

Comment: okay, my snippet will give you the result I described. event 2, 3, 4, 1. If you want to add the already started but haven't finished ProgrammData to the past events and want past events sorted ascending, that's another story.

Comment: I'm sorry for my mistake but the 3,4,2,1 is the correct order! Because on top are the future events, below the past events. The top 2 events are sorted ascending by start (Closer to now = more on top) and the bottom 2 events are sorted descending by end (Closer to now = more on top)

Comment: Okay, I made changes. Now it starts sorting with the ProgrammDatas which is not started yet ascending (so the closest to now will be the first). Then comes the rest (finished and ongoing) sorted by end times descending. So the ongoing ProgrammDatas first (which are haven't finished so end time in future) then the finished ones. Does it describe your original intention? If yes you could test the modified code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to split past and future events in different lists and sort them accordingly.
The final step is to join both lists.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ProgrammData programmData1 = new ProgrammData("a", LocalDateTime.now().plusDays(1),
        LocalDateTime.now().plusDays(1));
    ProgrammData programmData2 = new ProgrammData("b", LocalDateTime.now().plusDays(2),
        LocalDateTime.now().plusDays(2));
    ProgrammData programmData3 = new ProgrammData("c", LocalDateTime.now().minusDays(1),
        LocalDateTime.now().minusDays(1));
    ProgrammData programmData4 = new ProgrammData("c", LocalDateTime.now().minusDays(2),
        LocalDateTime.now().minusDays(2));

    List<ProgrammData> programmDataList = new ArrayList<>();

    programmDataList.add(programmData1);
    programmDataList.add(programmData2);
    programmDataList.add(programmData3);
    programmDataList.add(programmData4);

    final List<ProgrammData> collect = programmDataList.stream().sorted(Comparator
        .comparing(ProgrammData::end)).toList();

    LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
    final List<ProgrammData> pastEvents = collect.stream().filter(pd -> pd.end.isBefore(localDateTime))
        .sorted(Comparator
            .comparing(ProgrammData::end).reversed()).toList();
    final List<ProgrammData> futureEvents = collect.stream().filter(pd -> pd.end.isAfter(localDateTime)).toList();

    List<ProgrammData> sortedListAsRequired = new ArrayList<>();

    sortedListAsRequired.addAll(futureEvents);
    sortedListAsRequired.addAll(pastEvents);

    System.out.println(sortedListAsRequired);
  }

  static record ProgrammData(String name, LocalDateTime start, LocalDateTime end) {

  }
```

The result is something like this:

```
[ProgrammData[name=a, start=2022-02-23T18:08:59.564300200, end=2022-02-23T18:08:59.568806900], ProgrammData[name=b, start=2022-02-24T18:08:59.568806900, end=2022-02-24T18:08:59.568806900], ProgrammData[name=c, start=2022-02-21T18:08:59.568806900, end=2022-02-21T18:08:59.568806900], ProgrammData[name=c, start=2022-02-20T18:08:59.568806900, end=2022-02-20T18:08:59.568806900]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your example is confusing. As you state in the heading `event2` should be handled as if it's in the future, due it's end time (`2022-02-241800`) is after now (`2022-02-221200`), so the ordered elements shoud be

```
event2
event3
event4
event1
```

If that's correct, you could try something like the following:

```
events.sort((e1, e2) -> {
    // -1: e1 and e2 in the past
    //  0: e1 and e2 in distinct periods
    // +1: e1 and e2 in the future
    int period = Integer.signum(
          Integer.signum(e1.getEnd().compareTo(now))
        + Integer.signum(e2.getEnd().compareTo(now))
    );
    if (period == 0) {
        return -e1.getEnd().compareTo(now);
    }
    // > 0: e1 is after e2
    // = 0: e1 is equal to e2
    // < 0: e1 is before e2
    int comparation = e1.getComparingDateTime(now).compareTo(
        e2.getComparingDateTime(now)
    );
    return period * comparation;
});
```

Given

```
class ProgramData {
    ...
    public LocalDateTime getComparingDateTime(LocalDateTime reference) {
        if (reference.isAfter(end)) {
            // Past
            return end;
        }
        // Future
        return start;
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your example looks incorrect - event2 is in the future and should be sorted together with 3 and 4. Anyway, no matter what, you should split the list in 2, future and past events, and sort each accordingly. You could do it with a stream, or by splitting the list in two, pick whichever you like.

For setup:

```
public class ProgrammData {

    public static final DateTimeFormatter FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-ddHHmm");

    private String name;
    private LocalDateTime start;
    private LocalDateTime end;

    public ProgrammData(String name, String start, String end) {
        this.name = name;
        this.start = LocalDateTime.parse(start, FORMATTER);
        this.end = LocalDateTime.parse(end, FORMATTER);
    }

    //getters and setters

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ProgrammData{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", start=" + start +
                ", end=" + end +
                '}';
    }
}
```

1. Option 1 - streams

```
public class ProgrammDataMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //setup
        ProgrammData event1 = new ProgrammData("event1", "2022-02-220100", "2022-02-220300");
        ProgrammData event2 = new ProgrammData("event2", "2022-02-220200", "2022-02-241800");
        ProgrammData event3 = new ProgrammData("event3", "2022-02-251200", "2022-02-281500");
        ProgrammData event4 = new ProgrammData("event4", "2022-02-261600", "2022-02-262100");
        ProgrammData event5 = new ProgrammData("event5", "2022-02-220600", "2022-02-221159");

        LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.parse("2022-02-221200", ProgrammData.FORMATTER);

        List<ProgrammData> list = Arrays.asList(event1, event2, event3, event4, event5);

        //sort
        Comparator<ProgrammData> futureComparator = Comparator.comparing(ProgrammData::getStart);
        Comparator<ProgrammData> pastComparator = Comparator.comparing(ProgrammData::getEnd).reversed();
        list.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(pd -> pd.getEnd().isBefore(now),
                pd -> {
                    Comparator<ProgrammData> comparator = pd.getEnd().isBefore(now) ? pastComparator : futureComparator;
                    Set<ProgrammData> set = new TreeSet<>(comparator);
                    set.add(pd);
                    return set;
                },
                (s1, s2) -> {
                    s1.addAll(s2);
                    return s1;
                }))
                .entrySet().stream()
                .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
                .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
                .collect(Collectors.toList())
                .forEach(set -> set.forEach(System.out::println));
    }
}
```

First we stream the list and collect into `Map<Boolean, Set<ProgrammData>>`, true key would collect past events, false - future. Then stream map entries, sort by key to make sure future events - false key, are before past, and get values(sets). Because values are in `TreeSet` with according comparator, they are already sorted.

2. Option 2 - split list in 2, sort each list, collect in single list again

```
public class ProgrammDataMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //setup
        ProgrammData event1 = new ProgrammData("event1", "2022-02-220100", "2022-02-220300");
        ProgrammData event2 = new ProgrammData("event2", "2022-02-220200", "2022-02-241800");
        ProgrammData event3 = new ProgrammData("event3", "2022-02-251200", "2022-02-281500");
        ProgrammData event4 = new ProgrammData("event4", "2022-02-261600", "2022-02-262100");
        ProgrammData event5 = new ProgrammData("event5", "2022-02-220600", "2022-02-221159");

        LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.parse("2022-02-221200", ProgrammData.FORMATTER);

        List<ProgrammData> list = Arrays.asList(event1, event2, event3, event4, event5);

        //sort
        Comparator<ProgrammData> futureComparator = Comparator.comparing(ProgrammData::getStart);
        Comparator<ProgrammData> pastComparator = Comparator.comparing(ProgrammData::getEnd).reversed();
        //sort
        List<ProgrammData> futureList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<ProgrammData> pastList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (ProgrammData programmData : list) {
            if (programmData.getEnd().isBefore(now)) {
                pastList.add(programmData);
            } else {
                futureList.add(programmData);
            }
        }
        futureList.sort(futureComparator);
        pastList.sort(pastComparator);
        List<ProgrammData> resultList = new ArrayList<>(futureList);
        resultList.addAll(pastList);
        resultList.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Basically, make 2 new lists, one for future, other for past, sort each, add them in a new list. Or you could save them in the initial list.

Both options result in order - events 2, 3, 4(future, sorted by start ascending), events 5, 1(past, sorted by end descending).